# write to a txt file through a dll

Tags: c++, dll

I want to write to a text file through a dll, it compiles fine but it doesn't output the file with following code. When I compile the project to a .exe and run it, it can creat the file and write to the file.

What do I need to do to write from the dll??
I want to output some data inside the dll for debugging purpose, instead of return these intermediate data from the dll. I'm calling the dll from python/

credit.cpp

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

double*  _stdcall credit(double* in_array, double a, double b)
{

    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("example.txt");
    myfile << "Hi!\n";
    myfile.close();

    return in_array;
}
```

credit.def

```
LIBRARY "pass"
;DESCRIPTION 'call dll from python'
EXPORTS
    credit
```

credit.h

```
#pragma once
double* __stdcall credit(double a, double b, double *in_array);
```

Comment: How are you calling it? Did you run it through a debugger? Are you sure you're looking in the right directory for the file?

Comment: @Captain Obvlious I call the dll from Python. and I've searched the whole project directory of the visual studio  project

Comment: "it doesn't work" is not a description of the error you get, please edit to improve the question a bit... Also, have you tried with absolute path?

Comment: @hyde I updated the post. I mean it doesn't output any file.

Comment: You really need to get the result/error codes of your file operation. Printing to stdout or stderr works, I would think? Or use a debugger (not sure, but you *may* need a debug version of Python binary too for this to work, so debug prints might be easier).

Comment: I have the same issue with a C++ dll I call through C#, I have tried with the absolute path and the file is not created. @Lisa any updates on how to solve this issue you had?

Comment: @StutiRastogi no, I have not. Pls do come back if you have the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

From a DLL try using an absoulute path "C:\\Temp\\example.txt", make sure the folder is created first that should fix your problem.

I use the following bellow to write simple timing logs from a dll.

```
void Log(const std::string& text) {
    std::ofstream log("C:\\logs\\performance.log", std::ofstream::app | std::ofstream::out);
    auto ms = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(
        std::chrono::system_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
    auto p = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
    auto t = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(p);
    log << toString(text) << ", Since Epoch: " << toString(ms) << " time: " << toString(std::ctime(&t)) << std::endl;
}
```